# How can I use method split on ruby module?

Tags: ruby, macos, server, split, memcached

Hi everyone's try to use a split method in a module  but I can't, the terminal  give me this error: `` undefined method `split' for :"set algo":Symbol (NoMethodError) ``

```
class Server
    def initialize(port,ip)
      @server = TCPServer.open(ip,port)
      @connections = Hash.new
      @clients = Hash.new
      @connections[:server] = @server
      @connections[:clients] = @clients
      run
      split
    end

  def run
    loop{
      Thread.start(@server.accept) do | client |
        # for each user connected and accepted by server, it will create a new thread object
        # and which pass the connected client as an instance to the block
        request = client.gets.chomp.to_sym
        dev =  request.split(" ")
        client.puts dev[0]
         #if dev[0] ==  "set"
          #  client.puts "OPERACION VALIDA"
         #else
          #  client.puts "OPERACION INVALIDA "
          #  Thread.kill self
        #end
      end
    }.join
  end



end
 Server.new(3000, "localhost")
```

Comment: BTW, there's a stray `split` in the last line of `initialize`.

Comment: @anonimo342 : What effect do you want to achieve from _split_  applied to a **symbol**? Maybe you intended something like `request.to_s.split(//)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
request = client.gets.chomp.to_sym
```

With:

```
request = client.gets.chomp
```

Calling `to_sym` converts the string from `gets`/`chomp` to a symbol which doesn't implement `split`.

Comment: thanks!!  your answer resolve all my problems